# How to use get_statevector in Qiskit SDK 1.0?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, qiskit-runtime

I am Using Qiskit SDK 1.0. I have a problem with `get_statevector` in qiskit SDK 1.0 and using `BasicSimulator`. My code is attached below.

```
simulator = BasicSimulator()#Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = simulator.run(circ).result()#execute(circ,simulator).result()
sv = result.get_statevector(circ)
print(sv)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example here https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#basicaer-1 showing how it was done (previous) and what to do now (current), as below

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
 
qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.measure_all()
 
# Previous
from qiskit import BasicAer
backend = BasicAer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
statevector = backend.run(qc).result().get_statevector()
 
# Current
qc.remove_final_measurements()  # no measurements allowed
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
statevector = Statevector(qc)
```

Comment: (Not the OP) The problem with this is that, as far as I can tell it doesn't work when you need the statevectors after a partial measurement. According to the [documentation](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.result.Result#get_statevector), `get_statevector()` remains in the SDK in the 1.0 release but something with it's semantics seem to have changed

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an incorrect usage of `BasicSimulator`. `BasicSimulator` is intended to replace `QasmSimulatorPy` (not `StatevectorSimulatorPy`). For example, you can use `BasicSimulator` like this:

```python
from qiskit.providers.basic_provider import BasicSimulator
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)
circ.h(0)
circ.measure_all()

simulator = BasicSimulator()
result = simulator.run(circ).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
print(counts)
```

```
{'0': 517, '1': 507}
```

To get the statevector, you can still use `Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')` like this:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import Aer

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)
circ.h(0)

simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = simulator.run(circ).result()
sv = result.get_statevector(circ)
print(sv)
```

```
Statevector([0.70710678+0.j, 0.70710678+0.j],
            dims=(2,))
```

But the preferred method, as was stated in this answer https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/37240/27580, is to simply cast the circuit as a statevector using `Statevector(circ)`.